# Is the nonce in a HMAC useful to increase the security, to generate a random number based on the seed?

Tags: node.js, random, cryptography, numbers, hmac

To generate a number based on a seed, I written this code:

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),

//generate the crypto random token
clientToken = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(crypto.randomBytes(128)).digest('hex')
serverToken = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(crypto.randomBytes(128)).digest('hex'),

//generate the seed
hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha512', serverToken);
hmac.update(clientToken);
var seed = hmac.digest('hex'),

//generate the random number with a PRNG algorithm
prng = new require("seedrandom")(seed),
random = Math.floor(prng() * (100000000 - 10000)) + 10000;

//log the results
console.log("clientToken: ", clientToken);
console.log("serverToken: ", serverToken);
console.log("Seed     :   ", seed);
console.log("Random number:", random);
```

As you can see, I don't HMAC a nonce value and I would to know if digesting it, will add more security.

This could be the code updated with the nonce implementation added:

```
//generate the nonce by using a nanosecond timestamp
var hrtime = process.hrtime(),
nonce = (hrtime[0] * 1e9 + hrtime[1]).toString();
nonce = crypto.createHash("sha1").update(nonce).digest('hex');

//generate the seed
var hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha512', serverToken);
hmac.update(clientToken);
hmac.update(nonce);
var seed = hmac.digest('hex');
```

Adding the nonce, will increase the security ? An user that only knows the client token, could guess the hmac seed ? (With and without the nonce implementation)

Comment: So I assume the code is server side? What does the random number do? Because it doesn't seem to be just any "random number".

Comment: The client/server tokens and the nonce are generated server-side.

On the website I provide a client-side verification tool to verify the validity of the generated number.
The random number is a number that the users have to guess (it's a game with a provably-fair system = the script above)

Comment: Using the MT algorithm in such a scheme is highly suspect. The MT algorithm is *not* a PRNG, it is *not* designed to be one-way! If the servertoken is secure I don't think the nonce makes much of a difference, but it could be a nice backup in case `crypto.randomBytes(128)` fails. The more precise the timestamp the better of course.

Comment: Edited the question replacing with a PRNG algorithm and by using nanosecond precision over the timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be if you don't trust your random number generation enough to always generate a random number. In general it never hurts to add entropy to a scheme, as long as the method is secure. Often this means a hash or HMAC based construction.

If you can base all of your security on the `serverToken` then adding additional entropy doesn't seem to make much sense.